# How to use dynamic finders for embedded domain class in grails 3.3.11?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

This is my main domain class and i am using MongoDB.

```
Person{
    String id
    String name
    List<Address> addresses 
    static hasMany=[addresses: Address]
    static embedded =['addresses']
}
```

This is my embedded domain class

```
Address{
     String addressId
     String city
     static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
```

I want to update the Address using Address.addressId. Before updating the Address, I need to check if the Address belongs to the Person and Address.city is unique within one Person Object.
How can I use dynamic finder of grails to get Person Object using Address.addressId and Person.id
 to get list of Address.

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to limit your option to dynamic finders?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown No , But its easier to use.

Comment: "But its easier to use. " - We have added support for other query methods that are more performant, and in my view easier to use.  I would likely use a "where" query for what you are describing but if you can make it work with dynamic finders and that is easier for you, rock on!  :)

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am new to grails. Is it possible to get person object by providing addressId to the dynamic finder.